# Is it architecturally wrong for a client to listen to a JMS Queue?

Tags: java, rest, architecture, jms

Let's say you have a client which makes a rest server call and expects some sort of call back or updates after the server call is finished.

The server publishes these updates to a JMS queue and the client has a listener on the JMS queue.

I wonder if this architecture has a design flaw. For me it seems strange for a client to listen to a queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO Your client should use either REST or JMS, either synchronous or asynchronous communication.

You could use REST to send the request and wait or poll for the response.

Or you could use JMS to send the request as a message and listen for the response.  This is not idea as external client should be connecting directly to your JMS (or JDBC) infrastructure IMHO.

Or you could use websockets to give you a web based asynchronous messaging for the request and response.

In any case, I would try to use just one technology from the client, and let your server/gateway process do the everything else.

Comment: Unfortunately Websocket supports is not nearly as mature and simplified as REST support. There would be more handcoding involved in the routing process etc. Apps can safely combine synchronous REST with asynchronous STOMP.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik do you have a link for STOMP?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik and it appears to prefer STOMP over Websockets ;)

Comment: It uses Websocket as the transport for STOMP, which is a perfectly correct choice, I think, because STOMP adds JMS-like semantics (topic, named queue, etc.)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I agree STOMP is a useful addition to Websockets, though not a replacement.  I am not using this combination could be described as more mature either. It could be simpler/better as it is relatively standard.

Comment: Definitely not a replacement because it doesn't define the transport semantics. It is a nice, simple protocol to implement on the client side. Spring's support is quite mature, but client-side (JavaScript) not as much. At least last time I looked at it, which is already two years ago now. Time files...